# Run Python script with MSSQL-database connection on Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, odbc, pypyodbc

Im trying to run a script i wrote on a Ubuntu Server.

Im using pypyodbc to connect to a database on a server in the script, and it works great on Windows.

When im trying to run it on my Ubuntu Server i get the following error:

```
pypyodbc.Error: (u'IM002', u'[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified')
```

This is my connectionstring:

```
DRIVER = "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
SERVER = "SERVER=servername;"
UID = "UID=userid;"
PWD = "PWD=password;"
DATABASE = "DATABASE=database_name;"

connection = pypyodbc.connect(DRIVER + SERVER + DATABASE + UID + PWD)
```

What have i done wrong? Any thoughts?

Best Regards.

Comment: Show us how you have tried to make the connection, so we have a chance to find out what can be wrong with it.

Comment: I edited my original post, but here is the connectionstring:


`DRIVER = "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
SERVER = "SERVER=servername;"
UID = "UID=userid;"
PWD = "PWD=password;"
DATABASE = "DATABASE=database_name;"

connection = pypyodbc.connect(DRIVER + SERVER + DATABASE + UID + PWD)`

Can´t seem to get the formating right in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have `[SQL Server]` section in your `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file.
You should have something like this in it:

```
[SQL Server]
Driver=<driver so file name>
<other parameters>
```

The section name must be the same you used to set the `DRIVER` in your python program. You should choose an appropriate driver like freetds for that.
Check http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html